# Why is this one div container blocking the other from floating right?

Tags: css, html, containers

I know the answer is very simple, it's probably one little CSS property, but I've tried to find the solution without asking it here, no luck..

There are two div containers within a div container, and they aren't playing nice.

The one is positioned to float right in the upper righthand corner of the parent div, and it won't let any other container float to the right of it.

I tried `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` but no luck...

Here's the code, though something tells me the answer is so easy you won't need it!:

The parent div, the upper righthand corner div, and the poor div trying to float right:

```
    #um-home-section4   {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: green;
}

#um-title-right {
    float:right;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

#take-me-there  {
    float:right;
    margin-top:240px;
    margin-right:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: gray;
}




<div id="um-home-section4">
                <div id="um-title-right"></div>
                <div id="take-me-there"></div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the order in your HTML :

```
<div id="um-home-section4">
  <div id="take-me-there">
  </div>
  <div id="um-title-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

See this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/Rk4mr/11/**

Comment: Thanks, that totally did, and yes, it was incredibly simple ;)  So why is that, should divs be in order from rightmost to leftmost?

Comment: yes depends on what side are you floating the divs you need to know the order .. if is right the lastone is first in the html .

Comment: yes it stills reserve the space if you want thw two divs at right 0 then thnik in absolute position or making separate parents

Comment: position:absolute for the win!  Thanks.